# Can't connect via SSH to Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, raspbian-jessie

I have connected laptop and Raspberry pi 3 to one Wifi router. But I can't connect to Raspberry via SSH from my laptop. On raspberry SSH is **enabled** and I can connect to it from Raspberry itself. Here are some settings I have:

```
sudo service ssh status >>>>>>
ssh.serice - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Active: active (running)
raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server
raspberrypi sshd[503]: Server listeting on 0.0.0.0 port 22
raspberrypi sshd[503]: Server listeting on :: port 22
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ifconfig info
wlan0   inet addr:169.254.206.211 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask 255.255.0.0
```

I tried to connect on ubuntu like this:

```
ssh pi@169.254.206.211
```

And on windows via Putty

Comment: Are you using PuTTy? Have you checked the IP address for you Pi is correct?

Comment: I've tried on ubuntu and on windows - same effect, just didn't connect

Comment: I've edited question with **ifconfig** info

Comment: *"just didn't connect"* -> Can mean a few different things although the most likely one here is the node does not exist/is not visible.  You said you'ved "edited question with ifconfig info", but you didn't; just edit in the output of `ip addr` instead.  Then explain *exactly* how you are trying to connect from elsewhere and *exactly* what message you received, because I know it wasn't "just can't connect".

Comment: Does 'putty' hang or quit immediately ? If it hangs - maybe you have a firewall getting in the way ? Can you ping the pi from the same host ok ?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to set static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces`. This will not work. See the following tutorial

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

EDIT I may be misinterpreting what you have in `/etc/network/interfaces`. As posted this implies that you have added `wlan0   inet addr:169.254.206.211 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask 255.255.0.0`

In addition `169.254.206.211` will not work through a router. This is a `link-local` address and is not routable.

If you have not entered this it implies that DHCP has not assigned an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the setting of your WLAN Box? There must be a checkbox down in the menu. It must be activated so that your computers can "talk" directly to each other in your WLAN net.

Hope I could help you.

Regards